# compare two datatable value in if statement

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, datatable

```
 for (int i = 0; i < dtblAllDB.Rows.Count; i++)
 {                 
      if ((table.Rows[i]["customer_id"].ToString() && table.Rows[i]["time"].ToString() ) != (dtblAllDB.Rows[i]["customer_id"].ToString() && dtblAllDB.Rows[i]["time"].ToString() ))
      {

      }
 }
```

I need to compare two datatable column values, but I am getting the error,
here table and dtblAllDB are the datatables..

> Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&&` operand could be applied to `bool` but not `string`, your condition would be something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < dtblAllDB.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (!(table.Rows[i]["customer_id"].ToString() == dtblAllDB.Rows[i]["customer_id"].ToString() 
    && table.Rows[i]["time"].ToString()  ==  && dtblAllDB.Rows[i]["time"].ToString()))
    {
    }
}
```

Although this does not make much sense as it will compare the tables row by row and filter out row which does not match both `cutomer_id` and `time`

If you want to compare two tables irrespective of row position then you need two loops like shown below.

```
for(int k = 0; k < table.Rows.Count; k++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dtblAllDB.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (!(table.Rows[k]["customer_id"].ToString() == dtblAllDB.Rows[i]["customer_id"].ToString() 
        && table.Rows[k]["time"].ToString()  ==  && dtblAllDB.Rows[i]["time"].ToString()))
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ToString() returns a string that represents the current object. Use

```
Convert.ToString(table.Rows[i]["customer_id"])
```

in every case. And also use == to compare between strings

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare every value seperatly. I think this is what you want to do:

```
if ((table.Rows[i]["customer_id"].ToString() != dtblAllDB.Rows[i]["customer_id"].ToString())
    && ((table.Rows[i]["time"].ToString() != dtblAllDB.Rows[i]["time"].ToString())
    && (table.Rows[i]["customer_id"].ToString() != dtblAllDB.Rows[i]["time"].ToString())
    && (table.Rows[i]["time"].ToString() != dtblAllDB.Rows[i]["customer_id"].ToString()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use plus sign(+) to concatenate two strings in c#

```
if ((table.Rows[i]["customer_id"].ToString() + table.Rows[i]["time"].ToString()) != (dtblAllDB.Rows[i]["customer_id"].ToString() + dtblAllDB.Rows[i]["time"].ToString()))
   { }
```

OR

```
if (table.Rows[i]["customer_id"].ToString() != dtblAllDB.Rows[i]["customer_id"].ToString() && table.Rows[i]["time"].ToString() != dtblAllDB.Rows[i]["time"].ToString())
   { }
```